# Can i use flash file to create an application for ipad

Tags: flash, ipad

Can anybody suggest me how to call flash file in ipad application. Is it possible or not? Is there any way to call flash file in iPad application?  Can any body suggest me in details? waiting for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but to my knowledge, flash player is not supported in iOS, hence you will not be able to load your swf files. Recent news says that, Flash builder version 4.5 update is supposed to come in June, 2011 which will allow to build apps even for iOS.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot open SWF files directly with iPad, but it's been possible to create apps with Flash for iOs for a year or so.

Although using AIR 2.6 is recommended as it brings some serious improvements for it. AIR 2.7 is bringing more performance improvements as well, but I don't know when it's gonna be out.

To deploy iOs applications with AIR 2.6 you can use a lot of apps, Flash CS5 modifying some files, Flash CS5.5, Flash Builder 4 or higher, the plain commandline compiler, FlashDevelop, etc.